# ValueEventListener.onDataChange() doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listeners

For some reason when I call *getTitle*() in the fragment it always returns null.
It doesn't seem like the ValueEventListener gets added at all.

When I debug or print the value of *title* inside the listener, it does not print... Neither does the onCancelled(), but the ValueEventListener gets called.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? When I use a ChildEventListener directly in the view it works fine, so it's not the database connection.

JSON object:

```
"about" : {
    "info" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non suscipit risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in lectus consectetur nisl molestie luctus. Nulla commodo tincidunt dui ut dignissim. Suspendisse sapien lacus, tristique non ultricies nec, accumsan nec ipsum. Integer feugiat faucibus eros. Mauris augue ex, tincidunt a elit nec, pharetra aliquam nisl. Quisque viverra fringilla pulvinar. Nulla et vehicula ipsum, sed ultrices est. Maecenas bibendum ipsum quis erat cursus euismod. Nullam tempor diam eu eros ultrices, vel efficitur lacus bibendum. Cras auctor erat sem, quis auctor libero feugiat sit amet. Fusce semper odio at lacus faucibus, a feugiat massa suscipit. Pellentesque id est id massa faucibus faucibus quis eget libero.",
    "title" : "Vårt hotell er best i hele verden"
  },
```

The problem class:

```
public class AboutUsObserver extends AboutUs implements MyObserverInterface {

    private List<DataChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public AboutUsObserver(Query mRef){
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (child.getKey().equals("title")) {
                        String title = child.getValue(String.class);
                        setTitle(title);
                    }

                    else if (child.getKey().equals("info")) {
                        String info = child.getValue(String.class);
                        setInfo(info);
                    }
                }

                for (DataChangedListener listener : listeners)
                    listener.onDataChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addDataChangedListener(MyObserverInterface.DataChangedListener dataChangedListener) {
        listeners.add(dataChangedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListenerAt(int index) {
        listeners.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListeners() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

The AboutUs class:

```
public class AboutUs {

    public String title;
    public String info;

    // Required default constructor for Firebase object mapping
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public AboutUs(){}

    public AboutUs (String title, String info) {
        this.title = title;
        this.info = info;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info){
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
}
```

In a fragments onCreateView():

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference aboutRef = mRef.child("about");

        final TextView TITLE = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aboutTitle);
        final TextView INFO = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aboutInfo);

        final AboutUsObserver aboutUsObserver = new AboutUsObserver(mRef);

        aboutUsObserver.addDataChangedListener(new MyObserverInterface.DataChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                String test = aboutUsObserver.getTitle();
                TITLE.setText(aboutUsObserver.getTitle());
                INFO.setText(aboutUsObserver.getInfo());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AboutUsObserver` is expecting changes to children `title` and `info`.  It should be listening for changes to location `about`.  But you are initializing it to listen to the root location:

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
...
final AboutUsObserver aboutUsObserver = new AboutUsObserver(mRef);
```

Change to:

```
final AboutUsObserver aboutUsObserver = new AboutUsObserver(aboutRef );
```

Comment: Wow.. I can't believe I missed that, was debugging for hours. Well, I guess that's what might happen when you program for 8 hours straight. Thank you!